# Interfaces and public methods

Tags: c++, oop, c++11, inheritance, polymorphism

I have a struct that I use a pure abstract interface (only public methods and they're all `=0`), an abstract class to hide implementation details and two child classes that inherit from it.

I'd like to expose some public methods in those child classes as they only make sense in that context but marking them as public doesn't work as the compiler only seems to be able to see public methods in the interface. How can I make public methods in the child classes accessible?

**Update**

Interface:

```
class Result {
public:
    virtual ~Result() noexcept = default;

protected:
    Result() = default;
};
```

Abstract class:

```
template <typename T>
class AbstractResult : public Result {
public:
    AbstractResult();
    virtual ~AbstractResult() noexcept = default;
};
```

First child:

```
class AResult : public AbstractResult<PGResult> {
public:
    PGResult() = default;
    virtual ~PGResult() noexcept = default;

    void add_server_status(const char status) noexcept;
    void add_command_complete(const CommandComplete command_complete) noexcept;
    void add_columns(const vector<Column> columns) noexcept;
    void add_error(const Error error) noexcept;
    void add_notification(const Notification notification) noexcept;
};
```

I'd like to create an instance of `Result` and call `add_columns(...)` on it which is forbidden by the compiler:

```
unique_ptr<Result> result.reset(new AResult);
result->add_columns(...)
```

Comment: Can you show some of your code to look at as reference?

Comment: The calling code will have to use `dynamic_cast` to convert from a reference to interface into a reference to derived class (and tolerate an exception), and then call the method on the derived class.  (You can also dynamic cast pointers - you have to check the result for `nullptr`)

Comment: Can you elaborate on why you have an abstract class inherit from a concrete class? That's not a typical pattern in C++. Normally your abstract interface will define a minimal yet complete interface to all implementations, removing the need to know which implementation has been created.

Comment: @MarkB I want the interface to be as clean as possible with only public methods. Then I have an abstract class where I keep code common to implementations. I use CRTP for that.

Comment: When creating a complete and usable object requires more than calling its constructor, it is a string sign you need a factory.

Comment: `class AResult : public AbstractResult<PGResult>` -- this is not a specialization.  This is a class derived from `AbstractResult<PGResult>`.  Your `AbstractResult` template seems to do nothing; this may indicate confusion on your part.  A purely abstract class and an interface are the same thing in C++.

Comment: @Yakk - Things have been omitted for brevity.

Comment: @ruipacheco Sure.  Still, `AResult` is not a specialization.  Specialization is a term used in C++ to refer to a particular thing you can do with a `template`, and using it for something else in the middle of `template` code is worrysome.  Mixed with the pointlessness of the `template` and they add up.  Mixed with your lack of understanding of how methods are dispatched, and the lack of context in your question is disturbing.  There is quite possibly something you have omitted that makes your question and any answers very misleading.

Comment: @Yakk - I see your point. I've replaced the term "specialisation" with "child classes". Hope this makes the question clearer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks to me like when you create it you know the type, so stash that off before assigning it into the `unique_ptr`:

```
std::unique_ptr<AResult> temp(new AResult);
temp->add_columns(...);
unique_ptr<Result> result(std::move(temp));
```

Comment: If `add_columns` throws an exception you have a memory leak. I think it is preferable for `temp` to have type `unique_ptr<AResult>` and then move it to result.

Comment: Good point, forgot about exception safety - suggestion taken.

Comment: @ChrisDrew add_columns is noexcept and the code just adds a column to a vector. Are you saying composition would be a better solution in this case?

Comment: @ruipacheco I was just saying it is good practice to avoid raw owning pointers and manage `temp` with a `unique_ptr` as Mark has done in his edit.

Comment: Sorry, only saw the move now. Thanks!